# Schematron Assert Rule Fails while setting context

Tags: c#, xpath, namespaces, xsd, schematron

I am attempting to use  NMatrix's Schematron to validate XML in C#.
If I leave the "f" namespace out of the namespace-manager (nsManager), I get the exception: *Undeclared namespace prefix - f* when this code is executed.

```
CompiledXPathExpression _expr;
...
_expr.SetContext(nsManager);
```

For Schematron Line:

```
<sch:rule context="/f:Patient/f:identifier/f:period">
```

After adding the "f" namespace, the "rule" line completes, but I get the exception:
*Unrecognized extension function namespace: prefix='', namespace URI=''*
when the same code is executed.

```
CompiledXPathExpression _expr;
...
_expr.SetContext(nsManager);
```

For the next Schematron line:

```
  <sch:assert test="not(exists(f:start)) or not(exists(f:end)) or (f:start/@value &lt;= f:end/@value)">Inv-1: If present, start SHALL have a lower value than end</sch:assert>
```

After some experimentation, I find this works:

```
    <sch:rule context="/f:Patient/f:identifier/f:period">
      <sch:assert test="f:start">Inv-1: If present, start SHALL have a lower value than end</sch:assert>
   </sch:rule>
```

But this fails:

```
    <sch:rule context="/f:Patient/f:identifier/f:period">
      <sch:assert test="not(exists(f:start)) or not(exists(f:end)) or (f:start/@value &lt;= f:end/@value)">Inv-1: If present, start SHALL have a lower value than end</sch:assert>
end</sch:assert>
   </sch:rule>
```

I thought I had some kind of namespace problem at first, but now I am starting to wonder if this syntax is even valid with XPathExpression

Comment: Are you using XPath 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

This was a learning experience! NMatrix-Schematron is completely obsolete. It is no longer being worked and only supports Schematron 1.5 - very old.

I had a very difficult time locating a complete demonstration. I have included a link to a complete demonstration solution using Saxon-HE.

[sample code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DC00B7D9CE3B0F3E!19754&authkey=!AA4lQ76Eem8ZBIU&ithint=file,.zip)

Comment: You can now use XRouter's SchemaTron for native (.NET) ISO Schematron (with xpath2/xslt2). https://github.com/gap777/SchemaTron